# arr.push(arr.splice(n,1)) "swallows" the property of the moved object

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, splice, array-push

for example,I want to put the middle element to the last:

```js
let students=[
    {"name":"a","uid":"001"},
    {"name":"b","uid":"002"},
    {"name":"c","uid":"003"},
    {"name":"d","uid":"004"},
    {"name":"e","uid":"005"},
];
students.push(students.splice(students.length/2,1));
console.log(students.length);
for(let s of students){
  console.log(s.name+':'+s.uid+',');
}
```

but the property of last element becomes undefined, despite the number of elements unchanged, why would it happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`splice` always returns an *array*, even when only one element is being removed. If you want to `push` the removed `student`, you'll have to extract it from the array first, otherwise you're pushing an array to `students` (rather than a student object):

```js
let students=[
    {"name":"a","uid":"001"},
    {"name":"b","uid":"002"},
    {"name":"c","uid":"003"},
    {"name":"d","uid":"004"},
    {"name":"e","uid":"005"},
];
const [student] = students.splice(students.length/2,1);
students.push(student);
// or
// students.push(students.splice(students.length/2,1)[0]);
console.log(students.length);
for(let s of students){
  console.log(s.name+':'+s.uid+',');
}
```

Comment: This is a great explanation, splice ALWAYS returns an array. 
//students.push(students.splice(students.length/2,1));
[0] gets the element in the array
//students.push(students.splice(students.length/2,1)[0]);

More people should up vote this answer.

Answer (score -1):

**splice** method always returns array not object., so in your code 5th element is array so its giving undefined value., just replace this line it will work fine

```
students.push(...students.splice(students.length/2,1));
```

to know mare about **...** **(Rest Operator)** [click here](https://oprea.rocks/blog/what-do-the-three-dots-mean-in-javascript/)

```js
    let students=[
        {"name":"a","uid":"001"},
        {"name":"b","uid":"002"},
        {"name":"c","uid":"003"},
        {"name":"d","uid":"004"},
        {"name":"e","uid":"005"},
    ];
    students.push(...students.splice(students.length/2,1));
    console.log(students.length);
    for(let s of students){
      console.log(s.name+':'+s.uid+',');
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

`Splice` always returns the array, use `spread operator` to fetch object.

```js
let students=[
  {"name":"a","uid":"001"},
  {"name":"b","uid":"002"},
  {"name":"c","uid":"003"},
  {"name":"d","uid":"004"},
  {"name":"e","uid":"005"},
];

students.push(...students.splice(students.length/2,1));

for(let s of students){
  console.log(s.name+':'+s.uid+',');
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what you changed in the code and why does it solve the problem?

Comment: The splice was returning an array, so used the spread operator to go one level deep.

Comment: Cool. Edit the answer and put the explanation there. Answers shouldn't be just code dumps but explain the problem and the answer as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for feedback. I really appreciate it. :)